# if(x!=y) vs if(x==y)

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I have run the [PMD plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) in Eclipse against my code and I'm getting a high priority warning for  code similar to the one shown below:

```
 if(singleRequest !=null){
   // do my work
 }else{
   // do my other work
 }
```

PMD says `` `Avoid if (x != y) ..; else .. ``;

And the description of the error looks like this:

```
In an "if" expression with an "else" clause, avoid negation in
the test.  For example, rephrase:
if (x != y) diff(); else same();
as:
if (x == y) same(); else diff();
Most "if (x != y)" cases without an "else" are often return
```

but I still can't understand the impact  on my code. If someone could guide me with an example, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is this not just the plugin being dogmatic about your code structure?

Comment: It is "suggesting" to avoid the negative-case conditional. I think this is *rubbish* in this case as the "negative conditional" actually leads to the "positive case". Your code is fine.

Comment: It's not always a readability issue... The important things about readability standards is knowing when to ignore the warnings about them because the code is in fact more readable as written. If you think your logic is more meaningful to you written as not, write not. There's a reason that operator exists, if this were the case there wouldn't be a != operator. Keep in mind a lot of these style modules are written by people who are dogmatic about style precisely because they are, and they often represent their opinion which is arbitrary.

Comment: I've seen this advice given regarding C++ programming, often because the == and != operators can be overridden on classes, and the != operator typically just calls the == operator and negates the result, so the code ends up being two jumps instead of just one (thus slightly slower).  Don't see how that applies to Java, though, since you can't override operators.

Comment: I've been programming computers since 1971 and I have never read or heard of this so-called 'good style'.

Comment: It's all about improving understandability by avoiding double negation, which is like a doorkeeper telling you that you can only enter if you're *not not older than 21* (or, in your case, *not not null*, which is the same as *null*).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A number of PMD rules are more style opinions than correctness alerts.  If you don't agree with this rule or the rule doesn't match your project's coding standards, you could consider [suppressing warnings](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/suppressing.html) or even [configuring PMD to enforce only the rules you like](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/howtomakearuleset.html)

Answer (score 13):

PMD is a tool. PMD works based on heuristics. Someone decided upon this heuristic; that negative *conditionals* with else statements are not "good style".

However, in this case, as I have argued in my comments, *the code posted is how **I** would write it*. (In particular with `x != null`, but not exclusively to this construct.)

This is because I don't look at the *conditional* (excepting as it can be simplified; e.g. removing double-negatives as shown by Jim Kin) but rather I look at the logic of the *branches* or "flow".

That is, I place the positive *branch* first. In this case I contend that

```
if (x != null) {
  doValid         // positive branch
} else {
  doFallback
}
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
if (isValid(x)) { // it looks like a "positive conditional" now
  doValid         // still positive branch
} else {
  doFallback
}
```

and is thus positive *branch* first.

Of course, not all situations have such a "clear" positive flow, and some expressions might be expressed much easier in a negative manner. In these cases I will "invert" the branches - similar to what PMD is suggesting - usually with a comment stating the action at the top of the block if the positive *branch*/flow was reversed.

Another factor that may influence the conditional choice used is "immediate scope exiting" branches like:

```
if (x == null) {
  // return, break, or
  throw new Exception("oops!");
} else {
  // But in this case, the else is silly
  // and should be removed for clarity (IMOHO) which,
  // if done, avoids the PMD warning entirely
}
```

This is how ***I*** *consistently* (a few occasional exceptions aside) write *my* code: `if (x != null) { .. }`. Use the tools available; and make them work *for* you. See Steven's answer for how PMD can be configured to a more suitable "taste" here.

Answer (score 9):

It's a readability issue. Consider

```
if ( x != y ) 
{
}
else  // "if x doesn't not equal y"
{
}
```

vs.

```
if ( x == y )
{
}
else  // "if x doesn't equal y"
{
}
```

The latter example is more immediately identifiable. Mind you, I see nothing wrong with using negatives... it can make a lot more sense, consider

```
if ( x != null )...
```

Comment: No. It is not a "readability issue". It's a "PMD issue". I consistently use `if (isValid) { doValidWork } else { doFalbackWork }`. It just happens to be that the `!=` is used in the "isValid" conditional.

Comment: 'More immediately identifiable' *why?* I don't find any difference between the two cases. Your pseudo-comments don't impress me. There is a wrong-headed way to phrase anything.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason I would avoid using the negative-case is if it resulted in double-negatives, which might be confusing.

e.g.

```
if (!checkbox.disabled) {
    // checkbox is enabled
} 
else {
    // checkbox is disabled
}
```

Comment: Yes, this use *is* confusing. It is also different (in subtle but import ways) from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Who reads your code? You do. The compiler does. Or maybe the assistant of the lecturer. A co-worker, who can't make difference between == and != ? Hope not.

I can only think negatives being bad in complex expressions. (Context being: at least for me. I know I've frustrated in debugging in my head `while(!expr && !expr2 || expr3) { }`)

`ch=getch(); if (ch!='a')`  is a pattern that is easily extended to
`if (ch!='a' || ch!='b')` which is always true, while sounding semantically correct.

From performance standpoint, it's best to sort the probabilities.

```
if (more_probable) {
      ....
      unconditional_jump_to_end_of_block;
} else {
   ...
}
```

This choice should lead to better performance, as the there is no mis-prediction penalty in the more probable branch.

`if (p && p->next)` evaluated from performance standpoint gives poor results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to avoid having "not equals" in the if condition.  This is because when someone else looks at your code, there is a real possibility that the person might ignore the != and might jump to wrong conclusion about the logic of your program.

For your case, you may have to interchange the if logic with else logic and change != to ==

Comment: I believe any sensible programmer takes a look at _exactly_ at != vs. ==. More like the problem comes when combining logical expressions and semantical i.e. !disabled vs. enabled  or !notReady

Comment: I firmly believe that there is a lot of fantasy out there about what a future reader might and might not do. This is a typical example. *Who are* these mythical programmers who read != as == but not the other way around? Or can't understand !disabled? (Or can't remember grade 3 operator precedence, for another example?) I've never met one. The last time I had a major staff issue with incorrect coding styles was 1982.

Answer (score 1):

It's a balancing case of code readability vs. code organization. The warning is basically suggesting that it's confusing for people reading the code to navigate the negation of a negative.

My personal rule of thumb is, whatever you expect to be the "normal" case is what you should test for in the if. Consider:

```
 if (x != y) {
   // do work here...
 } else {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }
```

In this situation I'd say that the important work is being done in the `x != y` case, so that's what you should test for. This is because I like to organize code so that the important work comes first, followed by handling for exceptional cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's because "good style" says that if possible tests should be "positive", so:

```
if (singleRequest == null){
   // do my other work
} else {
   // do my work
}
```

Is easier to read because the test is "positive" (ie "equals" not "not equals"), and ultimately better readability leads to less bugs.

#### Edited

This is particularly the case with test like:

```
if (!str.equals("foo")) {
```

you can easily miss the `!` at the front, but if you make the test positive, it's a lot cleaner.

The only time you should have a negative test is when there's no `else` block - then a negative test is unavoidable unless you have an empty `true` block, which itself is considered a style problem.

Comment: Why is this "good style"? (Thanks for using quotes, btw :-) I consistently put the *positive work* as the first conditional branch, however. Thus my code is *consistent* in this manner, *independent* of `!=` or `==` (e.g. `x != null -> isValid(x)`). I don't have to wonder "Which *branch* is positive?"? I *know* in my code - the first one.

Comment: it's good style because it's a) consistent and b) our tiny human brains can understand positive test better when working out program flow.

Comment: I contend it is not the *conditional* that must be consistent, but the *branch* ("positive flow").

Comment: This is just begging the question. Not an answer.

Comment: @EJP No, it's really an answer. I can't understand why you would say this is not an answer. Basically, humans parse positive tests more readily than negative ones.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you can minimise the overall complexity and improve readability by returning or failing early and then continuing without indentation:

```
if (something == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("something must not be null");
}

// continue here
```